# How to get all values of a certain row in a "group by" in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want my query to show which entries were most reported (which works) with all reasons that were given (which doesnt work). With my current query I get only one reason instead of all of them. (I tried the function concat_ws(), but it seems to not be the right one). Can someone help out?

```
SELECT `entries`.`id`, count(`reports`.`id`) AS `amount`, 
concat_ws(', ',`reports`.`reason`) AS `reasons` 
FROM `entries` 
CROSS JOIN `reports` ON (`entries`.`id` = `reports`.`entry_id`) 
GROUP BY `entries`.`id` ORDER BY `amount` DESC
```

Comment: Check out the Proper syntax of conact_ws() it also expects atleast 2 strings. http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat_ws-function.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function:

```
SELECT
  `entries`.`id`,
   count(`reports`.`id`) AS `amount`, 
   group_concat(`reports`.`reason` SEPARATOR ', ') AS `reasons` 
FROM
  `entries` CROSS JOIN `reports`
  ON (`entries`.`id` = `reports`.`entry_id`) 
GROUP BY
  `entries`.`id` ORDER BY `amount` DESC
```